# Showing only 2 digits after dot in Double with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, numbers, double

`val yield = (((sun * air)/ (cel+pco))*100).toDouble()`
I have an assignment like this. As a result, it shows many numbers after the dot, for example 12.3456712345. I just want it to show as 12.34.

Comment: val df = DecimalFormat("#.##") 
df.format(your_value)